# How to display all records from today's UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to display all attacks which have happened today. This is the current SQL I have in my php page. However it doesn't display how many have happened today.

```
$TodayAttacks = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `logs` WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '-1' DAY) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()")->fetchColumn(0);
```

Comment: By "today", do you mean "since midnight today" or "within the last 24 hours"?

Comment: @DavidFaber Since midnight therefore it will reset for the next day

Answer (score 0):

If by "today" you mean "since midnight today", your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM logs
 WHERE date >= CURDATE();
```

If there is a possibility of date values in the log greater than today's date (hey, weird stuff happens!) then you want this (I advise against using `BETWEEN` for date comparisons):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM logs
 WHERE date >= CURDATE()
   AND date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

If you mean "within the last 24 hours", your query would look more like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM logs
 WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Hope this helps.

**EDITED per comments below**

If the `date` column is a Unix timestamp value (stored as `INT(11)`?) then the query should look something like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM logs
 WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE());
```

One could also do the following to get records from the last 24 hours:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM logs
 WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

**[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4f412/1).**

Comment: This is what I have and it still doesn't work - `<?php echo $TodayAttacks; ?>` `$TodayAttacks = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM logs WHERE date >= CURDATE();")->fetchColumn(0);`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it doesn't work" ... what result do you get? What happens when you try the query directly in MySQL?

Comment: The result I get on the webpage is 0 and the result I get when I execute the sql in phpMyAdmin is also 0.

Comment: Do you have data that make you think that those answers are wrong? If so, could you add it to the question?

Comment: I currently have this for running attacks which works perfectly fine if this is gives off any clues? `$RunningAttacks = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `logs` WHERE `time` + `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND `stopped` = 0")->fetchColumn(0);`

Comment: Are you storing `time` and `date` in separate columns? And are they unix timestamps or date types?

Comment: `time` is irrelevant in this case as that's related to how long the user set the attack as in seconds. However `date` is a unix timestamp.

Comment: @ZacRam, if `date` is a unix timestamp value (stored as `INT(11)`?) then you'll want to use something like the following: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4f412/1